# Javascript Split String on First Space

Tags: javascript, sorting, space

I have the following code as part of a table sorting script. As it is now, it allows names in the "FIRST LAST" format to be sorted on LAST name by "reformatting" to "LAST, FIRST".

```
var FullName = fdTableSort.sortText;
function FullNamePrepareData(td, innerText) {
  var a = td.getElementsByTagName('A')[0].innerHTML;
  var s = innerText.split(' ');
  var r = '';
  for (var i = s.length; i > 0; i--) {
    r += s[i - 1] + ', ';
  }
  return r;
}
```

It currently seems to sort on the name after the LAST space (ex. Jean-Claude Van Damme would sort on 'D').

How could I change this script to sort on the FIRST space (so Van Damme shows up in the V's)?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your function seems to return the correct results. However, if it is not sorted correctly you will need to show us the sort function and how the `PrepareData` is applied in it.

Comment: What is that variable `a` good for?

Comment: What if the first name has a space in it? I know somebody whose first name is "Anne Marie" (no hyphen).

Comment: @nnnnnn So far, all of our records in the database have either a single first name or the first name is hyphenated "Anne-Marie" so that isn't an issue (YET). I'm not really sure how we would attack it if we had records like "Anne Marie Van Damme", "Anne Marie Smith" and "Anne Van Damme". Luckily we don't have that problem yet though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of the `.split()` and the loop you could do a replace:

```
return innerText.replace(/^([^\s]+)\s(.+)$/,"$2, $1");
```

That is, find all the characters up to the first space with `([^\s]+)` and swap it with the characters after the first space `(.+)`, inserting a comma at the same time.

Comment: +1, but you might use Non-whitespace `\S` instead of not-Whitespace `[^\s]`

Comment: This seems to do quite well. What would be the difference between those two 'non-whitespace' examples?

Answer (score 2):

You can shorten that functio a bit by the use of [array methods](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array):

```
function FullNamePrepareData(td, innerText) {
    return innerText.split(' ').reverse().join(', ');
}
```

To put only the first name behind everything else, you might use

```
function FullNamePrepareData(td, innerText) {
    var names = innerText.split(' '),
        first = names.shift();
    return names.join(' ')+', '+first;
}
```

or use a [Regexp replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace):

```
function FullNamePrepareData(td, innerText) {
    return innerText.replace(/^(\S+)\s+([\S\s]+)/, "$2, $1");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know where the sorting happens; it sounds like you just want to change the reordering output.

The simplest would be to use a regexp:

```
// a part without spaces, a space, and the rest
var regexp = /^([^ ]+) (.*)$/;

// swap and insert a comma
"Jean-Claude Van Damme".replace(regexp, "$2, $1"); // "Van Damme, Jean-Claude"
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're after this:

```
    var words = innerText.split(' '),
        firstName = words.shift(),
        lastName = words.join(' ');
    return lastName + ', ' + firstName;
```

Which would give you "Van Damme, Jean-Claude"